# Redirect non www traffic and http traffic through https. Amazon AWS Apache server

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, httpd.conf

I am using Beanstalk and an ELB with an EC2 instance of Apache web server on Linux AMI. I have edited the httpd.conf to redirect http to https requests using Rewrites, which works. I am using a certificate with website.com and www.website.com are both listed. The https terminates on elb. When I add rules for non www(eg: website.com) to redirect to `https://www.website.com` the redirects happen in the url but no html content loads.

Any ideas to make non www and www to redirect to https?

[image: ELB Listener config]
[security groups with my instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLrR1.png)

Comment: Does your security group on ELB allow for https? If so, how are you routing the traffic?

Comment: These are the listener config for routing(image in question edit). The elb terminates the requests.

Comment: You probably have redirect loop, please paste the part of the httpd.conf that rewrites http to https

Comment: RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http  
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

Comment: @Parin Replace `%{HTTP:Host}` with `%{HTTP_HOST}` and see.

Comment: I tried it with that edit. The system runs as usual. www redirects to https.
And example.com goes to example.com and not https:// www.example.com